# Left Join in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I was going through an example of LEFT JOIN on w3schools.com.
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderID
FROM Customers
LEFT JOIN Orders
ON Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID
ORDER BY Customers.CustomerName;
```

The above query will return me all customers with No Orders as NULL Order ID+ All customers having Orders with their Order Ids

How should I modify this query so that it returns All Customers with No Orders + All Customers having Orders with Order date as '1996-09-18'

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Customers with no orders on that date; or with no orders at all, on any date? Either way, how have you tried to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want customers with *no orders* and those with a specific order date, then you want a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT c.CustomerName, o.OrderID
FROM Customers c LEFT JOIN
     Orders o
    ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
WHERE (o.CustomerID is NULL) OR (o.OrderDate = DATE '1996-09-18)
ORDER BY c.CustomerName;
```

If you wanted *all customers* with their order on that date (if they have one), then you would move the condition to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT c.CustomerName, o.OrderID
FROM Customers c LEFT JOIN
     Orders o
    ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID AND o.OrderDate = DATE '1996-09-18
ORDER BY c.CustomerName;
```

Note the difference:  the first filters the customers.  The second only affects what order gets shown (and `NULL` will often be shown).